# How to display duplicate items based on the quantity in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the field content :

```
item    qty
-----  -----
tea      2
```

I want to display as below

```
item   qty
----  ------
tea     1 
tea     1
```

How to create SQL query like above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ITEM VARCHAR(10),QTY INT)    

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'TEA',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COFFEE',3
```

If you have more than 1 type of item and you want to get the number of items, you can do with the following query.

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS      
(
    -- You will get each ITEM from your table
    SELECT ITEM,  QTY, 1     NEWQTY
     FROM #TEMP 
     UNION ALL
     -- Here it will loop and shows the repeated values of each ITEM 
     SELECT C1.ITEM,C1.QTY,NEWQTY + 1
     FROM   CTE C1
     JOIN #TEMP T1 ON C1.item= T1.ITEM
     WHERE  C1.NEWQTY < T1.qty
)
SELECT ITEM,
       1 QTY
FROM   CTE 
ORDER BY ITEM
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0049e/2) to view result

Answer (score 0):

Use `Recursive CTE`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT item,qty,1 num from yourtable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT item,
                qty,
                num + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  num < qty)
SELECT item,
       1 as Qty
FROM   cte
```

or use Tally table. It will have a better performance when compared to `Recursive CTE`

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
     e2(n)
     AS (SELECT 1 FROM   e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b) -- 10*10
     --e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 AS b), -- 100*100
SELECT a.item,
       1 AS qty
FROM   yourtable a
       JOIN (SELECT n = Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY n)
             FROM   e2) b
         ON b.n <= a.qty;
```

**Note :** Based on the `Quantity` you may have to increase the `cross join` of CTE's

Check [**here**](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) for more info